# How can I work with attributes of a belongs_to relationship in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, belongs-to

I have a couple of basic Rails problems that I'm having trouble finding relevant current (Rails 3+) information on. Here is the first:

How do I access attributes of a parent object to display them in the view? I have the following models:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
```

I'm using regular restful routes (do nested resources come into play here?) and the standard find methods in the Devices controller. In the view for devices I want to display the name of the site that owns the device, but everything I try gives me errors. How can I access and display the Site.name value for a given device?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what's wrong without seeing what you're trying. Compare the working example below with your technique. But first check that your device actually has a site, as explored here: [Rails belongs_to association, can't access owner's attributes when part of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411040/rails-belongs-to-association-cant-access-owners-attributes-when-part-of-a-col)

Try this in your rails console:

```
site = Site.create(:name => "Boston")
device = Device.create(:name => "hackatron")
site.devices << device
device.site.name  #=> "Boston"
```

You can see my full output in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1384738)

If that doesn't help pinpoint where your error is, please share some code and the errors you're seeing.

Comment: This console code worked perfectly. I have several sites and devices in the database, properly associated. But when I try to do this in the view: `<%= device.site.name %>' I get the error `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'. Thanks!

Comment: Actually wow, I just followed that link you posted and it totally nailed the problem. Each of my devices has a site_id but it looks like one of them is invalid. The 'unless' code works great to avoid the error. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. "unless nil?" is a good start, but it's better not to have nil values hanging around. Check out the Null Object Pattern, and Avdi Grimm's talk "Confident Code".

Comment: Very interesting, good point. I'll see if I can figure out a more graceful way to handle this.